# Structure padding and element access

Tags: c, alignment, structure, padding

I have understood the concept of structure padding and byte alignment to some extent.
But I need some clarification on the below question.Say the structure declared as below:

```
struct somejunk
{

    int a;
    char b;
    char c;
    int d;
    double e;
}
```

My guess is the structure gets the size of total 24 bytes, as 2 bytes get padded at the end of `char c` and 4 bytes padded at the end of `int d`. My question is how does the CPU fetches the individual elements? how does it fetches say element `char b`? does it read the first 8 bytes of the struct and parse it?

Answer (score 3):

The details depend on the particular hardware of course. However, note that a conforming C11 implementation must guarantee that each struct member is a separate memory location for the purpose of data races. That is, if you have a given object `somejunk junk`, then two separate threads must be able to modify `junk.b` and `junk.c` correctly without requiring any synchronization. Therefore, the size of `char` must be such that the hardware can perform such accesses without inventing writes to other memory locations.

For example, on x86, you can say `mov BYTE PTR [eax], 51` to set the value of the byte at `*eax`, and this must interoperate with other memory accesses at different addresses, regardless of the value of `eax`. The CPU's cache coherency  protocol has to figure out how to inform other CPUs' caches that and how it's is modifying the cache line containing `eax` so that the caches get dirtied appropriately.